# Haskell Diagrams crop image

Tags: haskell, haskell-diagrams

I'd like to be able to draw a bunch of shapes in Diagrams and crop the picture to a fixed size, leaving parts of the shapes in view (i.e. not completely occluding the shape)

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I found bounding boxes, but it seems they only do intersection/containment checks.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably looking for `rectEnvelope`. Cf. the [section of the manual about clipping](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/manual.html#clipping).